# Cargo install swc_cli not working with error

Tags: rust, swc, swc-compiler

Here is the Rust version

```
% cargo --version
cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)
```

When I use cargo to install `swc_cli`

```sh
cargo install swc_cli
```

Cargo install `swc_cli` not working with the following error:

```
error[E0277]: `Resolution` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
   --> /Users/chenwenl/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/swc_ecma_transforms_module-0.178.19/src/path.rs:239:33
    |
239 |         info!("Resolved to {}", target);
    |                                 ^^^^^^ `Resolution` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
    |
    = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Resolution`
    = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
    = note: this error originates in the macro `::core::format_args` which comes from the expansion of the macro `info` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /Users/chenwenl/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/swc_ecma_transforms_module-0.178.19/src/path.rs:242:13
    |
241 |         let mut target = match target {
    |                                ------ this expression has type `Resolution`
242 |             FileName::Real(v) => {
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Resolution`, found `FileName`
    |
help: you might have meant to use field `filename` whose type is `FileName`
    |
241 |         let mut target = match target.filename {
    |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> /Users/chenwenl/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/swc_ecma_transforms_module-0.178.19/src/path.rs:250:13
    |
241 |         let mut target = match target {
    |                                ------ this expression has type `Resolution`
...
250 |             FileName::Custom(s) => return Ok(self.to_specifier(s.into(), orig_filename)),
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Resolution`, found `FileName`
    |
help: you might have meant to use field `filename` whose type is `FileName`
    |
241 |         let mut target = match target.filename {
    |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `swc_ecma_transforms_module` (lib) due to 5 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `swc_cli v0.91.141`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/ht/ywtww6wd2p91hy7g1kxgtd900000gn/T/cargo-installevoHBf`.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.
```

How can I solve this problem?

I've tried reinstalling Rust, but it did not help.

Comment: You're much likely to get a faster response by creating an issue on [the swc repo](https://github.com/swc-project/swc). The crate failed to build on docs.rs as well.